# Open activity from url in chrome browser

Tags: android

I want to open my `Activity` when user clicks on certain `url`.
I created `intent-filter` this way:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mysite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/prefix/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When I open that `url` from my sms or notes it works fine (my activity opens), but when I click on that `url` from chrome browser it redirects me to the web-site.
I heard that there is a problem with `chrome 23+`, but I can not create any `url` that could redirect me to my `activity` from `chrome`.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my application, i am using as mentioned below (Please replace host, pathPrefix and port with your values). In my case i am using different host, port and pathPrefix for dev, qa and production. That is why i add all scenarios in intent filter. Its working fine for me. Could you please try like this.

```
<activity
        android:name=".SampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/sample"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <!--Dev-->
            <data
                android:host="dev.mysite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/your path/"
                android:port="4000"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="mysite.com"
                android:path="/your path/"
                android:port="4000"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <!--Qa-->
            <data
                android:host="qa.mysite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/your path/"
                android:port="8000"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="qa.mysite.com"
                android:path="/your path/"
                android:port="8000"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <!--Production-->
            <data
                android:host="mysite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/your path/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="mysite.com"
                android:path="/your path/"
                android:scheme="https" />          
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: And your URL runs the app from chrome? Is there some server settings?

Comment: Yes, my application will launch and open "SampleActivity" when url loading in any browser on matches of data in intent-filter. There is no settings from server side.

Comment: What is Android version you work with? Is it necessary to specify a port? I tried with port 80 and without it, but no success

Comment: Minimum API level 15 and traget API level 26. Port number based on the your url. Please try to add scheme with http and https. because urls will transform automatically from http to https while loading in browser.

Comment: I solved it! The problem was that my host is subdomain.subdomain.mysyte.com, and I had to specify just host = "mysite.com". Thanks anyway

Comment: Thats great, Welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153001/discussion-between-prakash-and-rainmaker).

Comment: it worked only once and now chrome doesn't ask for app to open this url. But still can launch my app through this url from sms.